# will closing a prepared statement close the resultset associated to it?

Tags: java, database, jdbc

I have a function which returns a resultset which is associted to a prepared statement.i am closing the prepared statement in the finally block.
it automatically closes the resultset also which i need to return.
what is an alternative way for this?
My code looks like this

```
Resultset fnName(){
  Resultset rs = null;
  PreparedStatement ps = new PreparedStatement();
  try{
    rs = ps.execute(<query string>);
  }
  catch(...){...}
  finally{
    ps.close().
  }
  return rs;
}
```

Comment: It depends on the implementation of the JDBC driver. Oracle driver will close the ResultSet too.

Comment: returning closed preparedstatement resultset is not possible. Store result set output into a specified bean and return that bean.

Comment: @TimothyTruckle Actually, the definition of `Statement` (superinterface) defines explicitly that closing the statement closes the `ResultSet` as well.

Comment: @JimGarrison Hopefully all implementers have seen that... ;o)

Answer (score 5):

You could have read the Javadoc (my emphasis):

> ```
> void close​()
>       throws SQLException
> ```
>
> Releases this Statement object's database and JDBC resources immediately instead of waiting for this to happen when it is automatically closed. It is generally good practice to release resources as soon as you are finished with them to avoid tying up database resources.
>
> Calling the method close on a Statement object that is already closed has no effect.
>
> Note: ***When a Statement object is closed, its current ResultSet object, if one exists, is also closed.***